# R Bootstrap Error - 'Original' Not Found

Tags: r, statistics-bootstrap, tweedie

I am trying to bootstrap the standard errors of the parameter estimates in a glm, and I'm having a little trouble with the bootstrap step.  I have defined my function as follows...

```
boot.fn=function(data,index){
          return(eval(substitute(coef(glm(glm.formula,
                      family = tweedie(var.power=1.5,link.power=0),
                      data=data,
                      subset=index,
                      weights=EXPOSURE_COLL
                      )))))  
}
```

...and this function runs without error on its own.  However, when I run the bootstrap...

```
set.seed(1977)
boot(coll.train,boot.fn,1000)
```

...I get the following error message:

```
Error in eval(expr, envir, enclos) : object 'original' not found
```

Any help anyone can provide is greatly appreciated!

Comment: You need to pass the formula in the boot function, and yu could also make life easy and pass the index to subset the data using `[`. You also dont need the `eval(substitute(` in this setting. So the function is 
`boot.fn <- function(data, index, glm.formula){
          coef(glm(glm.formula,
                      family = tweedie(var.power=1.5,link.power=0),
                      data=data[index,]
                      )) 
}` and call it with `boot(coll.train, boot.fn, 1000, glm.formula=yourFormula)`

Comment: Also please have a wee read of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-exampleIt is really helpful if you can provide an example that people can paste into their R session, and also provide all library calls. Cheers